# VBA create list with specific number of worksheets to print

Tags: excel, vba

I have never really worked with VBA and I am getting stuck on a simple problem.
Essentially I have a workbook with multiple worksheets. I Have a Macro which prints all worksheets to pdf. I want to change the macro to only print specific worksheets

Code sofar:

```
Sub Print_All_pages()

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets


ws.Select
nm = ws.Name

Dim Filepath As String

Filepath = Range("Destination").Value & "\Übersicht Bonus - " & Range("Month").Value & " " & Range("Year").Value & " - " & nm & ".pdf"
 
 
Range("A1:N35").ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=Filepath, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False


Next ws

Worksheets("Main Sheet").Activate

End Sub
```

I hav tried the following which doesn't work

```
For Each ws in Worksheets

If ws.Name = "Textbausteine Mail" Or ws.Name = "Overzichten verzenden" Or ws.Name = "Übersicht_Januar" Then

'Do nothing

Else

nm = ws.Name

Dim Filepath As String

Filepath = Range("Destination").Value & "\Übersicht Bonus - " & Range("Month").Value & " " & Range("Year").Value & " - " & ws.Name & ".pdf"


Range("A1:N35").ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=Filepath, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False


Next ws

Worksheets("Main Sheet").Activate
```

This however throws me the error compilation error Next without for

Here is the workbook setup:
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You're missing an `End If` in the second snippet. Also, put a `ws.` in front of any instance of `Range`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the quick reply So I tried it with the END IF before Next ws and
However I still got an error: The Error that I got was Runtime error 1004  The Method Select for the object _Worksheet failed
' 
End If
Next ws

Worksheets("Main Sheet").Activate'

Comment: So If I Put the End IF after Next ws I get the error: Error while compiling Next without for

Comment: If I put it above the Next ws I get the error Select for the Object Worksheet failed

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It's been a long day. Switch it back.

Comment: Create a exclusion list (dictionary or arraylist) of the names of the sheets you don't want to print.  Iterate over all your worksheets to compile a list of names (Collection?) that are not in the exclusion list.  Use this list to print worksheets by name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Export Range to PDF

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportToPDF()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim FilePathLeft As String
    With wb.Worksheets("Main Sheet")
        FilePathLeft = .Range("Destination").Value & "\Übersicht Bonus - " _
                & .Range("Month").Value & " " & .Range("Year").Value & " - "
    End With
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim FilePath As String
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        Select Case ws.Name
        ' do NOT export:
        Case "Textbausteine Mail", "Overzichten verzenden", "Übersicht_Januar"
        ' do export:
        Case Else
            FilePath = FilePathLeft & ws.Name & ".pdf"
            ws.Range("A1:N35").ExportAsFixedFormat _
                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                Filename:=FilePath, _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _
                OpenAfterPublish:=False
        End Select
    Next ws
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I can't quiet seem to get it to work. 
When I use your code I get the error: Runtime Error 1004 The Method Range for the Object Worksheet failed

Comment: The code assumes that all the worksheets, whose ranges you are trying to copy, contain the named ranges `Destination`, `Month`, and `Year`. So there is a possibility that the named ranges are in the main sheet but we don't know that. Please clarify.

Comment: I think I am just really doing something wrong. So I tried using the original code from my question ( first code block) When I try and run this I get the pdfs of Textbausteine Mail and Oversight verzenden However after printing these two the next Übersicht Januar throws the error Select for the Worksheet failed. Does this mean that the Code somehow can't access this worksheet ? 
Regarding your question On the Main Sheet I have the fields Destination, Month, and Year

Comment: I've modified my answer.